# From where I can specify which botium.json file to use if botium.json file is not stored in default location or saved with other name

Tags: automation, chatbot

Where can I specify botium configuration file in botium.spec.js file if it is not created with default name and path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to set the BOTIUM_CONFIG environment variable.
See https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/360603/Botium+Configuration+-+Capabilities

Comment: could  you please  help me how can i set up BOTIUM_CONFIG environment variable, I have used below script in package.json file.


"test_citycool": "BOTIUM_CONFIG=citycoolBotium.json mocha --reporter mochawesome --reporter-options \"code=false,reportTitle=Digital CityCool,inline=true,overwrite=false\" --exit spec/botium_citycool.spec.js",

getting below error : 'BOTIUM_CONFIG' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.